# Sort with Text Months

Tags: perl, sed, awk

Not sure the best way to accomplish this.

I get these results to a text file from a mysql query.  I would like to the sort 4th column with the oldest entry first.

`10.xxx.xxx.xxx 70:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  Wed Apr  3 17:00:52 2013  Mon Apr 15 09:42:33 2013 
10.xxx.xxx.xxx 70:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  Mon Apr  8 14:01:05 2013   Mon Apr 15 09:42:33 2013
10.xxx.xxx.xxx 70:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  Fri Apr  5 13:00:56 2013   Mon Apr 15 09:42:33 2013
10.xxx.xxx.xxx 70:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  Mon Apr  8 08:00:59 2013   Mon Apr  8 08:00:59 2013 10.xxx.xxx.xxx 70:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  Thu Mar 28 14:15:12 2013   Fri Apr  5 09:00:55 2013
10.xxx.xxx.xxx 70:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  Thu Mar 28 14:15:12 2013   Fri Apr  5 07:00:53 2013`

sort -r -k10 test does not seem to cut it.

Comment: I presume you actually want to sort on column 4 thorough 7 as one entity.

Comment: can't you add an order by clause to the sql query?

Comment: Try something like this `sort -nk12 -k9M -nk10,11 textfile`

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution using [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) (in the Perl standard library since 5.10.0) and a Schwartzian Transform.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Time::Piece;

say map  { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
    map  { [ $_, sortdate($_) ] } <DATA>;

sub sortdate {
  my $date = join ' ', (split)[2 .. 6];
  return Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')->datetime;
}

__END__
10.xxx.xxx.xxx 70:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Wed Apr 3 17:00:52 2013 Mon Apr 15 09:42:33 2013
10.xxx.xxx.xxx 70:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Mon Apr 8 14:01:05 2013 Mon Apr 15 09:42:33 2013
10.xxx.xxx.xxx 70:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Fri Apr 5 13:00:56 2013 Mon Apr 15 09:42:33 2013
10.xxx.xxx.xxx 70:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Mon Apr 8 08:00:59 2013 Mon Apr 8 08:00:59 2013
10.xxx.xxx.xxx 70:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Thu Mar 28 14:15:12 2013 Fri Apr 5 09:00:55 2013
10.xxx.xxx.xxx 70:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Thu Mar 28 14:15:12 2013 Fri Apr 5 07:00:53 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
(
FOR /f "tokens=1-7*" %%a IN (sqlout.txt) DO (
SET "month="
FOR %%m IN (01 Jan 02 Feb 03 Mar 04 Apr 11 Nov 12 Dec) DO IF NOT DEFINED month (
IF %%d==%%m SET month=!prev!
SET prev=%%m
)
SET /a day=100+%%e
ECHO(%%g!month!!day!%%f*%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h
)
)>tempfile.1

(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('sort tempfile.1') DO (
SET line=%%i
ECHO(!line:**=!
)
) >sortedoutput.txt

DEL tempfile.1 /F /Q
```

On the sample data, there are 8 significant columns. Of these, the fourth is month, fifth date, sixth time and seventh year. I have no idea what you mean by the "fourth" column being "the" date since there are two separate dates in each line.

The process simply picks up the fourth column and looks through a list of month numbers (2-digit) and month abbreviations. It's easier to save the previous element for use when the next is compared, so when the monthname matches the fourth column in %%d, the `month` variable is set, and that will turn off any further processing of the month.

**You may have noticed I've not listed all of the months** This gives you something to do. It obviously won't work unless all of the months are entered in the list.

Next we deal with the fifth column, and add 100 to the day number, producing a number from 101 to 131. These numbers all have three characters.

Next we `ECHO` out a string of

- the year from column 7 in %%g
- the 2-character month number in `month`
- the 3-digit augmented day number
- the time from column 6
- an asterisk
- each of the elements of the original line

Next step is to read each of those lines after sorting.

- set the sorted line into `line`
- echo everything from `line` except the part up to the first asterisk.

Comment: Ignore if you want a SED solution, of course. soz - wrong area!